# How does amplitude dimming (CCR) work?

Tags: led-driver, constant-current, dimming, amplitude-modulation

When a LED driver dims using constant current reduction (CCR), what voltage and current is sent to the LED chip at the various dimming levels?

Say I have

- a CCR-compatible LED chip which takes 500mA and 20V
- a 10W CCR LED driver with 6-52V output and 500mA output

How much current and voltage is running through the chip at

- 100% dimming
- 50% dimming
- 25% dimming
- 1% dimming

What happens if I replace the LED chip with another one which takes 500mA and is labeled for 5W (as opposed to 10W)? Won't it receive way too much voltage? How much is too much?

Extra bonus if you also can explain what happens when the driver is using hybrid dimming with amplitude modulation from 1% to 100% and then PWM from 0.1% to 1%.

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the dimming circuit? Current is "running through"; voltage is "across".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "CCR compatible LED"; any LED will work fine if you lower its current, that's the standard way of reducing brightness when you need something better than PWM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current is proportional to the dimming percentage.

For your example, if 100% is 500mA, then 50% is 250mA and 1% is 5mA.

Voltage will be whatever it takes for the LEDs to pass the defined current through them - at 100% it will be about 20V but will not be exactly 20V due to manufacturing tolerances and at lower currents it will be somewhat less.

If you replace a 500mA 10W LED with a 500mA 5W LED, the 500mA power supply still drives 500mA to LED. Only voltage is lower. 500mA * 20V = 10W and 500mA * 10V = 5W.

What happens during hybrid dimming is the constant current is set to 1% but then that 1% current is not applied constantly but using PWM, where 100% PWM is 1% current and 10% PWM is 1% current applied but 10% on and 90% off at some frequency so actual brightness is 0.1%.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting read! I have clarified the confusing part of the question.

Comment: And I edited the answer for that.